# Symfony 5.3 login error Invalid CSRF token

Tags: symfony, csrf, registration

I have an error when authenticating Invalid CSRF token under symfony 5.3 on all browsers on pc, registration does not work either.
I have seen several posts on this forum but nothing has worked so far. I let the symfony console to create the login controller and the security authenticator. I have this token error only on windows, authentication works on linux (chromium and firefox) and on mobile (chrome).

Thanks for any help I really don't see where this can come from.

it works in http the registration and the login and when I pass the same directory on a domain in https i have the message Invalid CSRF token.

I have no login on prod
It's my private machine. The site is hosted on a shared server (1&1).

Comment: Can you please provide your config files? Are you working with your pc in a company network or is it your private machine?

Comment: please provide what you have in logs